# Why locally created struct can't be send to another thread?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, struct, d, spawn

why in D I can't send to another thread through Tid.send local instances of structs?
I would like to make simple handling of thread communication like this:

```
void main()
{
    ...
    tid.send(Command.LOGIN, [ Variant("user"), Variant("hello1234") ] );
    ...
}

void thread()
{
    ...
    receive(
       (Command cmd, Variant[] args) { ... })
    )
    ...
}
```

If I understand it correctly, D should create the array of Variants in the stack and
then copy content of the array the send function right? So there should not be any 
issues about synchronization and concurrency. I'm quiet confused, this concurrency is
wierd, I'm used to code with threads in C# and C.

Also I'm confused about the `shared` keyword, and creating shared classes.
Usualy when I try to call method of shared class instance from non-shared object, the
compiler throws an error. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should idup the array and it will be able to go through, normal arrays are default sharable (as they have a shared mutable indirection)

as is the compiler can rewrite the sending as

```
Variant[] variants = [ Variant("user"), Variant("hello1234") ] ;
tid.send(Command.LOGIN, variants);
```

and Variant[] fails the [hasUnsharedAlias](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#hasUnsharedAliasing) test

you can fix this by making the array shared or immutable (and receiving the appropriate one on the other side)

Comment: I tried shared, but on the other side I can't call the get function: Error: non-shared method std.variant.VariantN!(20u).VariantN.get!(Tid).get is not callable using a shared object  
How to solve this? Or should I rather use immutable?

Comment: true, so I decided to solve it by creating my own simplified Variant, becauase as I can see when i want to make some struct shared or immutable, methods owned by the struct have to be also shared or immutable...